# jQuery append result from php not showing

Tags: php, jquery, append

Hi I think I'm doing something wrong in my jQuery. I'm working on an online booking system and after choosing a treatment and date I want to dynamicly show a list of available timeslots. I have a php file which creates an array and echoes back the results in a SELECT OPTION list. I've tested with another file, and the jQuery post function works so the problem is for sure getting the results to show. The following is my first page jQuery. On changing date the SELECT list disappears.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dates").load('input_date.php');
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        onClose: function() { 

            var $form = $( "#input" ),
            treat = $form.find( 'input[name="treatment"]' ).val(),
            book = $form.find( 'input[name="bookdate"]' ).val(),
            url = "input_date.php";

            $.post( url, { treatment: treat, bookdate: book  },
                function(data) {
                    var content = $( data ).find( '#timeslots' );
                    $( "#dates" ).empty().append( content );    
                }

        );
    }});
});
```

this is my php file:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
error_reporting(0);
$treatment = $_POST['treatment'];
    $bookdate = $_POST['bookdate'];
if(isset($treatment) && isset($bookdate)){

$exp = explode("-", $bookdate);

//determine what day of the week it is
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$exp[1],$exp[0],$exp[2]);
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp); // sun0,mon1,tue2,wed3,thur4,fri5,sat6
echo $dw."weekday"; //week day 
echo"<br/>";

//find bookings with same date
$q = mysql_query("SELECT BOOK_SLOT_ID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE BOOK_DATE='$bookdate'");
//make array of booking slots
$array1 = array();
while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
$array1[] = $s['BOOK_SLOT_ID'];
}
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT SL_ID FROM SLOTS");
//make array of all slots
$array2 = array();
while ($s2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
$array2[] =  $s2['SL_ID'];
}

//remove bookings from all slots
$arr_res = array_diff($array2, $array1);

//make selectable options of results
echo "<SELECT id="timeslots">";
foreach($arr_res as $op){
$r = mysql_query("SELECT SL_TIME FROM SLOTS WHERE SL_ID='$op'");
$q3 = mysql_fetch_array($r);
echo "<OPTION value=".$op.">".$q3['SL_TIME']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</SELECT>";
}else{
$else = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SLOTS");
echo '<SELECT>';
while($array_else = mysql_fetch_array($else)){
echo "<OPTION value=".$array_else['SL_ID'].">".$array_else['SL_TIME']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</SELECT>";
print $bookdate;
}

?>
```

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com please insert English links on SO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to me security flaws, but how is this helping my problem?

Comment: @feeela Oops... I did not notice I switched languages. Sorry. Here is [SQL Injection in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: `alert(content);` and see if you are getting the result in that variable

Comment: maybe you should replace /echo "<SELECT>";/
with /echo '<SELECT id="timeslots">';/ ?

Comment: @air4x debugging in JavaScript in he year 2012: `console.log( content );` Most developer tools allow you to expand the objects that were outputted. Thus you could easily find out the contents plus its type of an object several levels deep. (e.g. using Chromium's "Developer-Tools" or Opera's "Dragonfly")

Comment: try `$(content).html();` and show the result

Comment: Is `$( "#dates" )` the `SELECT` itself? If yes, you can't append a new select to it. You need to append to its parent.

Comment: @feeela I agree regarding `consoloe.log()`.

Comment: no, #dates is the div the content should be loaded into
@ feela console log shows undefined. @airax $(content).html() shows undefined also. I guess the problem is in finding the #timeslots

Comment: Have you used `console.log(content);` just after ` var content =...` ? Also add `console.log(data);` and see if the expected data is available from the ajax request.

Comment: content and data are both undefined.. I think the problem is:var content = $( data ).find( '#timeslots' ); Perhaps it can't find it because it is in another page?

it makes sense, the code does all it should do (removing the result, just not replacing because it doesn't take the information from #timeslots

Comment: Try changing `echo "<SELECT>";` in your php page to `<SELECT id="timeslots">';`. There must be `id="timeslots"` for `find('#timeslots')` to work. But if there is nothing in data, it won't work.

Comment: I have changed that already but it still gives me undefined, thanks for your input though I really appreciate your involvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $( data ).find( '#timeslots' );
                    $( "#dates" ).empty().append( content );    
                }
```

this is the error

```
$( data ).find( '#timeslots' );
```

returns an `object`

you can use

```
$( data ).find( '#timeslots' ).text();// or html()
```

Comment: I've tried them both like this: 
    function(data) { var content = $( data ).find( '#timeslots' ).html();
     alert(console.log(data)); 
     $( "#dates" ).empty().append( content ); }
 But it still returns undefined, also with text instead of html

Comment: @JakeRowsell use `$("#dates").html(content);` instead of `$( "#dates" ).empty().append( content );`

Comment: It still alerts undefined.. I think the problem is in finding #timeslots content..